# What layers should I use for Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am building a sample project in Keras.  The project is to identify the difference between cats and dogs.  I found an [example](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) online with the model as such:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

My question is, how do people know which layers to use?  Are there guidelines or rules of thumb when to use `Conv2D` vs a `Conv1D` vs a another layer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short - they don't. Coming up with the good architecture is a majority of current deep learning research. There are some rules of thumbs, intuitions, but mostly - experience or coping existing ones that were reported to work.

In really short words:

- convolutions are used when you have spatial and/or temporal structure in data thus images, videos, sound etc.
- pooling has similar use cases to convolutions, it still requires spatial and/or temporal structure (unless it is applied to the whole channel/dimension) and provides a way of removing "details" (usually noise) and reduce dimension of the signal
- recurrent when your data has sequential character
- fully connected are needed to "force" a given dimension (thus often used as a last layer) or when one does not really know any structure that can be exploited (since they are pretty much the most generic ones)

However the question how to compose, what hyperparameters to use, how many to use is a huge open research question, and at the very beginning the best approach is to copy someone else's architectures and gain some experience/intuition what works and what does not for the data you are working with.

Comment: thank you for those rules of thumb.  I know this is a REALLY broad question but those guidelines are super helpful to get started with.  What about pooling layers?  If you have any other tidbits I bet there are a bunch of people that would find it super helpful that are learning about ML through Keras.

Comment: Pooling is similar to convolutions in the usecases (added to the answer)

Comment: thank you!  this really helps.  There is so much out there it is hard to figure our where to get started and how the concepts are connected.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: If there were a "Cliff notes" version of what these did, that would be amazing: Core Layers, Convolutional Layers, Pooling Layers, Locally-connected Layers, Recurrent Layers, Embedding Layers, Merge Layers, Advanced Activations Layers, Normalization Layers, and Noise layers.  Love your webpage btw.  Reading it now.

Comment: @Alexis, I found this explanation about Dense, Convolutional, Fully connected, Pooling, Normalisation layers useful. You can check it: https://forums.fast.ai/t/dense-vs-convolutional-vs-fully-connected-layers/191